# Time Zone causing UILocalNotification to be set for incorrect time

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdateformatter, uilocalnotification

I know this is similar to some other questions, but I cannot seem to get an answer and apply it to my situation and get it to work. I am using an NSDateFormatter to try to schedule an alert for 8:00 AM in the morning, no matter the time zone. Here is my code:

```
[self scheduleNotificationAtTime:@"08:00 AM"];
```

and then my method

```
-(void)scheduleNotificationAtTime:(NSString *)time {

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
format.dateFormat = @"HH:mm a MM/dd/yy";
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",time,self.array[2]];
//self.array[2] = is today's date, so today it is 6/13/14
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateString];
UILocalNotification *lnf = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Time zone %@",[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]);
lnf.fireDate = date;
lnf.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is today",self.navigationItem.title];
lnf.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:lnf];
NSLog(@"%@",lnf);
```

}

and the log statement at the end is reading

```
{fire date = Friday, June 13, 2014 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time,
time zone = America/New_York (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight), repeat interval = 0,
repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = (null), user info = (null)}
```

so it is 8 hours off! its 12:00 AM instead of 8:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
format.dateFormat = @"HH:mm a MM/dd/yy zzz";
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ EDT",time,self.array[2]];
```

then also

```
lnf.timeZone = [UITimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EDT"];
```

this should keep the time zones in sync.

Answer (score -1):

please try making this change :

lnf.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

to

lnf.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];

Comment: this does not work. I get 4 AM. It's closer, but still not right... This also seems like it is fudging it, not the correct way to fix it, right? @user3739364

Comment: why the downvote? was just trying to let you know of different timeZone setting. I don't know what time zone you're in, so I suggested it.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. It was someone else. (You need 125 rep to downvote, you can see i don't have that). I'm in EST or EDT. Any other ideas?